# How can I upgrade to gnome-shell 3.6 from 3.2?

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, gnome-shell

I have Linux Mint 12 which has gnome-shell 3.2.2.1 but I would like to update it to 3.6.

So my question is how do I upgrade it?

And also, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't doesn't do anything, how can I get that working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have apt-get installed?
If so...
`apt-get update`
`apt-get install gnome-shell` *this command will make sure that gnome-shell is installed and latest version*

Or better yet...

`apt-get upgrade` *just upgrade everything*

I don't run Linux Mint, but anyway, this is how you do it. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I tried these already but _I think_ Linux Mint doesn't have 3.6 in their repositories because it tells me that I have the latest version installed.